# Error 450 Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I want to select a specific word in a .docx using vba excel and then replace it by a BookMark, to do it i want to select the word so i have this code

```
With word_fichier
        With Selection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute FindText:="#tableauxvdd"
        End With
End With
```

But i have the 450 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Selection` refers to Excel not Word as you didn't qualify it. You can use:

```
    With word_fichier.Application.Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute FindText:="#tableauxvdd"
    End With
```

assuming `word_fichier` was a `Document` variable.

Comment: You also need to change 'wdFindContinue' to a literal value if you haven't added a reference to the Word object model.

Comment: wdym by "add a reference to the Word object model" ? for this code this is what i wrote 'Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")' is it good for a reference to the word object model ?

Comment: @Rory omg i forgot the '.application' :( thanks man

Comment: *Selection* should be used at all in this case. Instead, use *With word_fichier.Range.Find*